# Calling a dynamically loaded DLL method through reflection, but the target references a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dll

I need to dynamically call a method in a bunch of DLLs that are also mine. There is an unknown amount of DLLs to call and they might be in different versions. I dynamically load each DLL and invoke a static method within them using reflection. Basically my code looks like this

```
foreach (var myThing in instances)
{
    try {
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(myThing.DllPath);
        Type t = a.GetType("MyNamespace.Services");
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Backup");
        bool b = (bool)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { "Autobackup"+date+".zip", "Bot" });
    } catch (Exception e){
        LogInternalExceptions(e); // recursively vomit e.InternalException into logs
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Backup` method lives in a static class that references another DLL (log4net).

```
public static class Services
{
    private static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Services));

    public static bool Backup(string filename, string comment)
    {
        // ... snip ...
        Log.Info("Aww right, Princess!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, I get the expected error `Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, ...' or one of its dependencies. File not found.`.

I'm sure that this is not my only issue with this method, but it's the first one and I'm stumped. I can edit the caller or the target code, but I don't really know how. The target is an Asp.net MVC3 application, but the class is just a pretty generic general purpose service class.

I would wnat to use something like a preprocessor statement in the target; something like

```
#if REFLECTION
Log.Info("Aww right, Princess!");
#endif
```

But I know that makes no sense, because it's not in that stage, how else could I avoid this issue?

Adding log4net reference to the caller project doesn't really solve the big picture. Meaning that if I have some references other than log4net, they would still causes an issue.

Comment: It just never ever makes sense to fret about this on a web server.  It's not like you ever have a 3rd party that may or may not copy software onto the server.  Just deploy the assemblies you need, problem solved.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure if I followed you :). The thing here is that I have many MyDLLs which all might reference different 3rd party DLLs, and when I update the MyDLLs, some of them might get new 3rd party DLLs referenced, such as Zipping backups or DLLs for Delta-Difference backups. Also some of them contain the same zip DLL in different versions and also I'm so lazy that I don't want to update the caller program, I want to forget it and leave it to generate email reports and not have it fail when I update my various sites. Maybe I am too lazy, yeah... good point :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly.LoadFile does not resolve dependencies which leads to the exception you describe. Using [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) should resolve your issue.